# catalina.out increases in size rapidly, using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, log4j, tomcat7, slf4j

Somehow my catalina.out's sizes is increasing rapidly.

After one run of my application the catalina.out is 12MB big and my opendata.log is 1MB big.
Why is not everything written to the opendata.log?
And how can i stop that these files grow so much?

The catalina.out and my opendata.log is full of [TRACE] messages.

This is my log4j.properties:

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/home/dzimmermann/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/logs/opendata.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.rootLogger=info, file

log4j.logger.org.hibernate=info, file
```

And this is my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
   "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
   "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgis/public/</property>
      <property name="connection.username"></property>
      <property name="connection.password"></property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
      <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
      <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect</property>
      <property name="show_sql">false</property>
      <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>      
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>       

      <mapping resource="Car.hbm.xml"/>
      <mapping resource="CarDetail.hbm.xml"/>
      <mapping resource="District.hbm.xml"/>
   </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the logging configuration being used isn't the one you think is being used. Try starting with the system property `log4j.debug` set, and it will tell you what config file is being used.

Comment: Glad I could help! I recommend editing your comment to clean up the language so a moderator won't have to do it in the future.

Comment: Mh i cant edit it anymore. I will delete and post it here again:
Ha! You are right! I changed my log4j.properties file locally and uploaded the war file to the server and also restarted the tomcat, but still the old file was used. Now the new file is used and it is working. ;-)